# Brownian Motion generator applied on indicator function.

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

We know that for a vanishing real-valued $C^2$-function $f$ and a brownian motion $B$ we have
$$\frac{d}{dt}\mathbb{E}_x[f(B_t)]=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\mathbb{E}_x[f(B_t)]$$
Now, i have seen the following. Let 
$$\Phi_t(x)=\mathbb{P}(B_t\leq x)$$
which is the distribution function of a normal distribution with parameters $(0,t)$. Then it holds
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_t(x)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\Phi_t(x)$$
I don't understand why this is true or where this comes from. How to rewrite 
$$\Phi_t(x)=\mathbb{E}_x[f(B_t)]$$ with suitable $f$ such that $f$ is in the domain of the generator of brownian motion?

Comment: For your first sentence, is it a well-known result in Brownian motion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote by $$p_t(y) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left(-\frac{y^2}{2t} \right)$$ the density of $B_t$. Then $$\Phi_t(x) = \mathbb{P}(B_t \leq x) = \int_{(-\infty,x]} p_t(y) \, dy.$$ Differentiation with respect to $t$ yields

$$\frac{d}{dt} \Phi_t(x) = \int_{(-\infty,x]} \frac{d}{dt} p_t(y) \, dy.$$ Since $$\frac{d}{dt} p_t(y) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{dy^2} p_t(y)$$ we get $$\frac{d}{dt} \Phi_t(x) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{(-\infty,x]} \frac{d^2}{dy^2}p_t(y) \, dy = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} p_t(x).\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, the fundamental theorem of calculus gives

$$\frac{d}{dx} \Phi_t(x) = p_t(x)$$

and so

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \Phi_t(x) = \frac{d}{dx} p_t(x).\tag{2}$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ proves the assertion.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} E^x[f(B_t)] &=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2} E^x[f(B_t)] \quad\quad (*) \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_t(x) &=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}\Phi_t(x) \quad \quad \quad (**)
\end{align*}
where $\Phi_t(x)= P(B_t\leq x)$.

The answer given by @saz already explained why $(*)$ is true.

For your other question

> *...How to rewrite $\Phi_t(x)$ with suitable $f$ such that $f$ is in the domain of the generator of Brownian motion [so that $(*)$ can be
>   viewed as an instance of $(**)$]?*

the answer is no, $(*)$ should **not** be viewed as an instance of $(**)$. Not even formally with $f$ being an indicator function.

Equation $(*)$ is a special case of the *Kolmogorov backward equation*, and $(**)$ is related to the *Kolmogorov forward equation*. In general they are dual to each other. In the special case of Brownian motion, they turn out to be similar because the infinitesmal generator
$$
A = \frac{1}{2}  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}
$$ is self-adjoint and the transition density 
$$
p_t(x,z) = P^x( B_t \in dz )
$$
is symmetric in the backward variable $x$ and forward variable $z$.

In general, given Ito diffusion $(X_t)$ with $X_0 = x$, the Kolmogorov backward equation is
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}  E^x[ f(X_t) ] =  A E^x[ f (X_t) ].
$$
where $f \in C^2$ and $A$ operates on the backward variable $x$.
The special case when $X = B$ is precisely $(*)$.

On the other hand, let $p_t(x,z) = P^x( X_t \in dz )$ be the transition density of $(X_t)$, then the Kolmogorov forward equation is
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}  p_t(x,z) =  A^* p_t(x,z)  
$$
where $A^*$ is the adjoint operator of $A$ operating on the forward variable $z$.

For Brownian motion starting a $x$, the infinitesmal generator $A$ is self-adjoint, i.e. $A = A^*$, with 
appropriate domains. Moreover $ p_t(x,z) = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi t} }e^{-\frac12 \frac{(x-z)^2}{t}}  $ implies that
$$
A^* p_t(x,z) =  A  p_t(x,z)
$$
where $A^*$ operates on $z$ and $A$ operates on $x$. So
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}  p_t(x,z) =  A  p_t(x,z), 
$$
which leads to $(**)$.